# VSCode Gulp Sass installation blows up when I haven't finished a line but hit save or it saves automatically when there's no ;

Tags: node.js, sass, error-handling, gulp

I'm not super familiar with golf at this point, but there's gotta be a way to configure error handling this. It can't always just freak out when there's no `;` at the end while you're in the middle of typing, your SCSS, right?

What am I missing? Researched this and can't seem to find an answer. And it's really annoying that this isn't just built into VS code seeing as Sass, SCSS, and Less are some of the most common plug-ins in any project in 2023. It shouldn't be this hard...

It just seems to be choking when it encounters half-done code. Rather than handling it.

Thanks.

Gulpfile directly from VS Code documentation site:

```
// Sass configuration
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));

gulp.task('sass', function (cb) {
  gulp
    .src('*.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(
      gulp.dest(function (f) {
        return f.base;
      })
    );
  cb();
});

gulp.task(
  'default',
  gulp.series('sass', function (cb) {
    gulp.watch('*.scss', gulp.series('sass'));
    cb();
  })
);
```

Error:

```
node:events:491
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
<ref *1> PluginError: Expected expression.
   ╷
44 │   bottom: ;
   │           ^
   ╵
  styles.scss 44:11  root stylesheet
    at Object.wrapException (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:1252:43)
    at SpanScanner.error$3$length$position (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:76246:15)
    at SpanScanner.error$1 (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:76249:19)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_singleExpression$0 (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:108600:17)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_expression$3$bracketList$singleEquals$until (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:108275:40)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_expression$0 (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:108509:19)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_declarationOrBuffer$0 (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:107112:31)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_declarationOrStyleRule$0 (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:107049:35)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_statement$1$root (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:106941:162)
    at ScssParser0._stylesheet0$_statement$0 (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:106944:19)
Emitted 'error' event on Domain instance at:
    at Transform.emit (node:domain:540:12)
    at Transform.onerror (/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:640:52)
    at Transform.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Transform.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  formatted: 'Error: Expected expression.\n' +
    '   ╷\n' +
    '44 │   bottom: ;\n' +
    '   │           ^\n' +
    '   ╵\n' +
    '  styles.scss 44:11  root stylesheet',
  line: 44,
  column: 11,
  file: '/Users/studio/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game/styles.scss',
  status: 1,
  messageFormatted: '\x1B[4mstyles.scss\x1B[24m\n' +
    'Error: Expected expression.\n' +
    '   ╷\n' +
    '44 │   bottom: ;\n' +
    '   │           ^\n' +
    '   ╵\n' +
    '  styles.scss 44:11  root stylesheet',
  messageOriginal: 'Expected expression.\n' +
    '   ╷\n' +
    '44 │   bottom: ;\n' +
    '   │           ^\n' +
    '   ╵\n' +
    '  styles.scss 44:11  root stylesheet',
  relativePath: 'styles.scss',
  message: 'styles.scss\n' +
    'Error: Expected expression.\n' +
    '   ╷\n' +
    '44 │   bottom: ;\n' +
    '   │           ^\n' +
    '   ╵\n' +
    '  styles.scss 44:11  root stylesheet',
  __safety: undefined,
  _stack: undefined,
  plugin: 'gulp-sass',
  showProperties: true,
  showStack: false,
  domainEmitter: Transform {
    _readableState: ReadableState {
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: 16,
      buffer: BufferList { head: null, tail: null, length: 0 },
      length: 0,
      pipes: [
        Pumpify {
          _readableState: ReadableState {
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 16,
            buffer: [BufferList],
            length: 0,
            pipes: [WriteStream],
            pipesCount: 1,
            flowing: true,
            ended: false,
            endEmitted: false,
            reading: true,
            sync: false,
            needReadable: true,
            emittedReadable: false,
            readableListening: false,
            resumeScheduled: false,
            destroyed: false,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            awaitDrain: 0,
            readingMore: false,
            decoder: null,
            encoding: null
          },
          readable: true,
          _events: [Object: null prototype] {
            end: [Array],
            close: [Array],
            prefinish: [Function (anonymous)],
            newListener: [Function: removeSink],
            removeListener: [Array],
            unpipe: [Function: onunpipe],
            error: [Function: onerror],
            finish: [Function],
            data: [Function: ondata]
          },
          _eventsCount: 9,
          _maxListeners: undefined,
          _writableState: WritableState {
            objectMode: true,
            highWaterMark: 16,
            finalCalled: false,
            needDrain: false,
            ending: false,
            ended: false,
            finished: false,
            destroyed: false,
            decodeStrings: true,
            defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
            length: 0,
            writing: false,
            corked: 0,
            sync: true,
            bufferProcessing: false,
            onwrite: [Function (anonymous)],
            writecb: null,
            writelen: 0,
            bufferedRequest: null,
            lastBufferedRequest: null,
            pendingcb: 0,
            prefinished: false,
            errorEmitted: false,
            bufferedRequestCount: 0,
            corkedRequestsFree: [CorkedRequest]
          },
          writable: true,
          allowHalfOpen: true,
          _writable: DestroyableTransform {
            _readableState: [ReadableState],
            readable: true,
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 7,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            writable: true,
            allowHalfOpen: true,
            _transformState: [Object],
            _destroyed: false,
            _transform: [Function: normalize],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          _readable: DestroyableTransform {
            _readableState: [ReadableState],
            readable: true,
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 8,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            writable: true,
            allowHalfOpen: true,
            _transformState: [Object],
            _destroyed: false,
            _transform: [Function: writeFile],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          _readable2: DestroyableTransform {
            _readableState: [ReadableState],
            readable: true,
            _events: [Object: null prototype],
            _eventsCount: 8,
            _maxListeners: undefined,
            _writableState: [WritableState],
            writable: true,
            allowHalfOpen: true,
            _transformState: [Object],
            _destroyed: false,
            _transform: [Function: writeFile],
            [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
          },
          _autoDestroy: false,
          _forwardDestroy: false,
          _forwardEnd: true,
          _corked: 0,
          _ondrain: null,
          _drained: true,
          _forwarding: false,
          _unwrite: [Function: clear],
          _unread: [Function: clear],
          _ended: false,
          [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
        }
      ],
      flowing: true,
      ended: false,
      endEmitted: false,
      reading: true,
      constructed: true,
      sync: false,
      needReadable: true,
      emittedReadable: false,
      readableListening: false,
      resumeScheduled: false,
      errorEmitted: true,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      destroyed: true,
      errored: [Circular *1],
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: false,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      awaitDrainWriters: null,
      multiAwaitDrain: false,
      readingMore: false,
      dataEmitted: false,
      decoder: null,
      encoding: null,
      [Symbol(kPaused)]: false
    },
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      prefinish: [Function: prefinish],
      end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onend] },
      data: [Function: ondata]
    },
    _eventsCount: 3,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    _writableState: WritableState {
      objectMode: true,
      highWaterMark: 16,
      finalCalled: false,
      needDrain: false,
      ending: true,
      ended: true,
      finished: false,
      destroyed: true,
      decodeStrings: true,
      defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
      length: 0,
      writing: false,
      corked: 0,
      sync: false,
      bufferProcessing: false,
      onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
      writecb: null,
      writelen: 0,
      afterWriteTickInfo: null,
      buffered: [],
      bufferedIndex: 0,
      allBuffers: true,
      allNoop: true,
      pendingcb: 0,
      constructed: true,
      prefinished: false,
      errorEmitted: true,
      emitClose: true,
      autoDestroy: true,
      errored: [Circular *1],
      closed: true,
      closeEmitted: false,
      [Symbol(kOnFinished)]: []
    },
    allowHalfOpen: true,
    _transform: [Function (anonymous)],
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
  },
  domainThrown: false
}
 ✘ studio@ians-mac-mini  ~/GeneralAssembly/projects/Baby Bumper/Baby Bumper Game   master ±✚ 
```